# Valid characters for file name in the #include directive

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

What are the valid characters for the file name in the `#include` directive?

Under Linux, for example, I can use pretty much any character except `/` and `\0` to have a valid file name, but I would expect C preprocessor to be more restrictive about the names of files I can include.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, the source character set is defined in [[lex.charset]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#1):

> The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space character, the control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:14
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " '

And the grammar for `#include`s is anything in the source character set except for characters that would mess with the `#include` parsing: newlines and `>`/`"` depending ([[lex.header]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.header)):

> ```
> header-name:
>     < h-char-sequence >
>     " q-char-sequence "
> h-char-sequence:
>     h-char
>     h-char-sequence h-char
> h-char:
>     any member of the source character set except new-line and >
> q-char-sequence:
>     q-char
>     q-char-sequence q-char
> q-char:
>     any member of the source character set except new-line and "
> ```

So something like this is perfectly<sup>†</sup> fine:

```
#include <hel& lo% world$@-".h>
#include ">.<>."
```

---

<sup>†</sup>For some definition of "perfectly" anyway...