# <command-line>:0:3: warning: ISO C++11 requires whitespace after the macro name

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, macros

I am compiling qt sources (C++) on different version of Ubuntu OS (14.04 and 16.04 LTS). The sources compile (g++) on 14.04 LTS without warnings. But on 16.04 gives following warnings "<command-line>:0:3: warning: ISO C++11 requires whitespace after the macro name warnings".

I am wondering what causes this error? Thanks in advance.

g++ --version: 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: It would help if you include the actual, complete warning message, but I bet the warning is caused by a missing space after a macro name.

Comment: And a few lines of code around the source of the error.

Comment: The compiler is not giving the exact location of code (file name and line number). Actually the total warnings are as follows "<command-line>:0:19: warning: missing terminating " character
<command-line>:0:3: warning: missing terminating " character
<command-line>:0:3: warning: ISO C++11 requires whitespace after the macro name". I don't know if that helps to give a solution.

Comment: Does it not even include the name of the macro (assuming the macro isn't called 'name')?

Comment: In line with my answer, it would help to have some details about how you are trying to build your executable.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a `g++` command line with an invalid `-D` option. (Or perhaps more than one of those.)

The second two warnings can be triggered by

```
g++ '-DFOO"unterminated' ...
```

(Note the missing `=` after `FOO`.)

Since you're probably using some build system, the likely cause is an incorrect build configuration which gives rise to an unterminated quote in the `-D` argument. (Although it is also not unlikely that the quote itself was unintentional.)

Comment: @NarsiReddyAnugu: As I said, it's impossible to be more precise without knowing more. If you could paste the actual `g++` command into your question, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This error is also caused by invalid characters in your define name. I had the same error trying to do this:

```
g++ -Dsomedefine++=1
```

Comment: Additional discussion of valid C++ characters which might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977940/valid-characters-for-file-name-in-the-include-directive

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because of commas present in macro VALUE...

```
-DPRED='WSum<4,Pixel>'
```

escaping the comma solved the problem

```
-DPRED='WSum<4\,Pixel>'
```